# Read Hadoop DFS data in a bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop

I have a file in the Hadoop DFS at a location say /test/filename.txt.

This file has the data of type:

```
bool array
```

for example:

```
true [1, 2, 4, 6]
```

I need to read this file in a bash script and store the boolean value and the list in two separate variables. I am not very familiar with bash but I know the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example with "read line to array" will help :

```
/path/to/hadoop dfs -cat /test/filename.txt | while read -a line; do echo "boolvar is ${line[0]}"; echo "array is ${line[1]}"; done
```